# iOS: Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView retainCount]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an error warning:
I usually put a distpach_async on the main thread to avoid the problem, but impossible to found the function **-[UIView retainCount]** in my code.

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView retainCount]
PID: 71660, TID: 11215956, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.keyboard.xpc, QoS: 25
Backtrace:
4   liboainject.dylib                   0x0000000128d09ca4 _AllocationsObjcLogger + 74
5   liboainject.dylib                   0x0000000128d09e0e ___swapMethods_block_invoke_3 + 301
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x0000000110e91bab _Block_object_assign + 207
7   UIKit                               0x000000010df0f4f6 __copy_helper_block_.2638 + 31
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x0000000110e918f0 _Block_copy + 113
9   UIKit                               0x000000010e996dcc -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry initWithTask:] + 77
10  UIKit                               0x000000010e995a2c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTaskOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:] + 119
11  UIKit                               0x000000010df0f498 __70-[UIKeyboardImpl syncInputManagerToKeyboardStateWithExecutionContext:]_block_invoke + 90
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4a336c __invoking___ + 140
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4a3240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
14  Foundation                          0x000000010b5b85ce __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 17
15  Foundation                          0x000000010b7e488a -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 790
16  Foundation                          0x000000010b7e89b0 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke.346 + 505
17  libxpc.dylib                        0x000000011117c61c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
18  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001111719cc _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 82
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110da439f _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dbc5b7 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 369
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dac57d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 434
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dad1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110db0102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dafda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011126f1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011126ec4d start_wqthread + 13
2018-01-21 15:51:21.776157+0100 Formbox_Renault_Showroom_Zoe Levallois[71660:11215956] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView retainCount]
PID: 71660, TID: 11215956, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.keyboard.xpc, QoS: 25
Backtrace:
4   liboainject.dylib                   0x0000000128d09ca4 _AllocationsObjcLogger + 74
5   liboainject.dylib                   0x0000000128d09e0e ___swapMethods_block_invoke_3 + 301
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x0000000110e91bab _Block_object_assign + 207
7   UIKit                               0x000000010df0f4f6 __copy_helper_block_.2638 + 31
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x0000000110e918f0 _Block_copy + 113
9   UIKit                               0x000000010e996dcc -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry initWithTask:] + 77
10  UIKit                               0x000000010e995a2c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTaskOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:] + 119
11  UIKit                               0x000000010df0f498 __70-[UIKeyboardImpl syncInputManagerToKeyboardStateWithExecutionContext:]_block_invoke + 90
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4a336c __invoking___ + 140
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4a3240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
14  Foundation                          0x000000010b5b85ce __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 17
15  Foundation                          0x000000010b7e488a -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 790
16  Foundation                          0x000000010b7e89b0 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke.346 + 505
17  libxpc.dylib                        0x000000011117c61c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
18  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001111719cc _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 82
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110da439f _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dbc5b7 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 369
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dac57d _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 434
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dad1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110db0102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110dafda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011126f1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011126ec4d start_wqthread + 13
```

Do you have any idea where to found it, so I could use :

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both stack traces you've posted start at level 4. Where's the first three levels of each stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some of the memory management debugging tools turned on simultaneously with the main thread checker.   One of the memory debugging tools is swizzling retain/release to do some additional memory management analysis and that analysis includes a call to `retainCount`, which UIView requires to be called from the main thread.

I.e. you're using two tools that are incompatible with each other.  Turn one off.

As well, please file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com.   The developer tools should either prevent you from using this configuration or should give a better runtime diagnostic.